# Is there a UNIX command to list all recently removed files from a system

Tags: linux, rm, deleted-files

Accidentally a `rm -rf` command was launched to my root directory instead of current directory. I stopped file removing by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> but some files has already been removed. Is there a LINUX command to list all recently removed files from the system to get the affected applications ?

Operating System: CentOS 6.3

Comment: You should compare the current list of files with the same list of your backup medium.

Comment: What does "my root directory" mean?  Are you referring to your home directory or to the system root directory?

Comment: Multi-site-post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23356096/is-there-any-way-to-list-recently-deleted-files-by-rm-rf-command-in-linux

Comment: @Anthon, That one also posted by me and MikeW asked me to post on this Linux & Unix forum. Old one is put on hold as off-topic.

Comment: @John1024 it is system's root directory (It happen accidentally)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*nix systems typically have a `locate` utility installed.  It has a database, usually updated nightly, that has the names of (almost) all files on your system.  Just run:

```
locate /path/to/dir/of/interest
```

and you should see a list of files that were in that directory as of the last database update.  You can diff this against the current list.

Because it will be overwritten automatically with a new version, you might make a back-up copy of that database now.  On debian-influenced systems, it is stored in `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db`.

#### How to show missing files

1. Make a backup of the old database:

   ```
   cp /var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db ~/old.db
   ```
2. Update the database.  The command to do this may vary.  On a debian-like system, try:

   ```
   sudo /etc/cron.daily/mlocate
   ```
3. Get the new and old file lists for your directory:

   ```
   locate -d ~/old.db /your/dir | sort >~/old.list
   locate /your/dir | sort >~/new.list
   ```
4. Get a list of all new and missing files:

   ```
   diff ~/old.list ~/new.list
   ```

#### Additional notes

- Not all files are listed in locate's database.  A configuration file, typically `/etc/updatedb.conf`, determines which files and directories are excluded.
- In the past I have used some version of `locate` that, by default, would only list files that still exist.  If that is the case for your `locate`, you will want to turn that feature off.

Comment: I could check with locate command and using my backup system to compare the lists. I already found some effected applications. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For arch I was afraid I accidentally deleted lots of files with a bad fin ... | xargs rm -rf command format. John1024 thank you for the advice.

To simplify everything (for my web-directory /srv/http) I run this all in one line:

`sudo cp /var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db ~/old.db; sudo updatedb; sudo locate -d ~/old.db /srv/http | sort >~/old.list; sudo locate /srv/http | sort >~/new.list; sudo diff ~/old.list ~/new.list;`

Make sure you replace /srv/http with your directory of concern.

and this displays the files that were changed. Thanks again!