# Create and report system acivity

Tags: linux, debian, logs, monitoring

I have a set-up a server running several applications. There will be multiple people using these applications in a community situation. I am looking for a way to track and report changes made to certain files and dirs. There is already a MTA setup, so I am looking for a way to generate logs of activity on specified locations and then mail them once a day. Can anyone offer any advice on where to start?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the processes that you want to monitor then you can use "lsof" command to see the file a particular process or command is using. Please see below for an example :

$$ lsof -p "pid_of_process"

Even if you do not know about process then also you can use lsof periodically to collect system information about files used by a process.

If you are interested in complete system activity, then "sar" utility should be used

Comment: I see that lsof can track what processes make changes to certain dir.  Can I use it too buid a report of what files were added or removed? With something like `lsof +D /var/log/ -u USER -a` ?

Comment: @TomRuh,  I dont think that for added or removed files you should use lsof. Because lsof gives list of open files only. If there are files that are not opened at a particular instance then that will not be shown . I think that following post is useful for your case [link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127027/is-there-a-unix-command-to-list-all-recently-removed-files-from-a-system)